# Tensorflow SxN matrix multiply with SxD matrix to output SxNxD array

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a matrix SxN where each K_ij is a scalar

```
[[K_11,K_12,K_13,..,K_1N],
 [K_21,K_22,K_23,..,K_2N],
 ..,
 [K_S1,K_S2,K_S3,..,K_SN]]
```

Another matrix SxD such that each X_i is a Dx1 vector

```
[X_1,
 X_2,
 ...,
 X_S]
```

I want a results such that gives me

```
[[K_11 * X_1],[K_12 * X_1] ..., [K_1N * X_1],
 [K_21 * X_2],[K_22 * X_2] ..., [K_2N * X_2],
 [K_31 * X_3],[K_32 * X_2] ..., [K_3N * X_3],
  ......,
  [K_S1 * X_S],[K_S2 * X_S] ..., [K_SN * X_S]]
```

where * stands for multiply

Any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: In Python, I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you want:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

K = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])  # (S, N)
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])  # (S, D)
# All-to-all product: (S, N, D)
result = K[:, :, tf.newaxis] * X[:, tf.newaxis, :]
# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # (2, 2)
    K_val = np.array([[10., 20.],
                      [30., 40.]])
    # (2, 3)
    X_val = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
                      [4., 5., 6.]])
    # (2, 2, 3)
    result_val = sess.run(result, feed_dict={K: K_val, X: X_val})
    print(result_val)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 10.  20.  30.]
  [ 20.  40.  60.]]

 [[120. 150. 180.]
  [160. 200. 240.]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what Im looking for

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (using TF APIs):

```
tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(in1, axis=2), tf.expand_dims(in2, axis=1))
```